# How to get the Workspaces which the user has permission in Rally Java rest

Tags: java, rest, rally

I need to get the list of workspace to which the user has access using Rally Java rest api.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a get on the current subscription and include Workspaces in your fetch.  You will probably also want to include Name and State.

```
GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest("/subscription");
getRequest.setFetch("Workspaces", "Name", "State");
GetResponse getResponse = restApi.get(getRequest);

JsonObject subscription = getResponse.getSubscription();
JsonArray workspaces = subscription.getAsJsonArray("Workspaces");
for (JsonElement w : workspaces) {
    JsonObject workspace = w.getAsJsonObject();
    System.out.println(String.format("\t%s: %s",
        workspace.get("Name").getAsString(),
        workspace.get("State").getAsString());
}
```

Note that this only works with WSAPI 1.x versions since in WSAPI 2.x child collections (like Workspaces) are not returned.  The same basic concept will work in 2.x, but it will require an additional request to read the Workspaces collection from the subscription.